# Coded UI Tests: WaitForControlEnabled throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

I'm writing tests for windows application and trying to wait when button will be enable.

```
var mainWindow = new WinWindow();
mainWindow.SearchProperties[WinControl.PropertyNames.ControlName] = "mainWindow";
mainWindow.SearchConfigurations.Add(SearchConfiguration.AlwaysSearch);
mainWindow.SetFocus();

//toolbar with needed button
var toolbar = new WinToolBar(mainWindow);
toolbar.SearchProperties[UITestControl.PropertyNames.Name] = "toolbarName";

var button = new WinButton(toolbar);           
button.SearchProperties[UITestControl.PropertyNames.Name] = "buttonName";
button.DrawHighlight();
button.WaitForControlEnabled();
```

So, button is disabled but exists. `button.DrawHighlight()` works fine and draw a border around button.

But `button.WaitForControlEnabled()` throws `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object` without waiting the time-out.

If i'm using `button.WaitForControlReady()`, it throws same exception without waiting the time-out even button exists and enabled.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post a full stacktrace?

Comment: Which version (ie update) of Visual Studio 2013 are you using?

Comment: @AdrianHHH it's not a duplicate, i'm interested in waiting for enabled control. I'm updated my VS 2013 from Update 3 to Update 5 and exception is gone. Now if control disabled, `WaitForControlEnabled(5000)` returns false. But it's still not waits for time-out even if i set `PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyTimeout = 5000`.

Comment: So it is a duplicate. The null reference exception appears to be due to a fault fixed in a update to Visual Studio. Your point about waiting for a timeout is a different question.

Comment: @AdrianHHH Should I create another question or update this?

Comment: I suggest creating a new question.

Comment: @AdrianHHH ok, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your code is properly written. If DrawHighlight is working with the control then its instantiated. Maybe the problem with your version of Visual Studio Coded UI. If you are waiting for clicking the button, try something like this. Hope this works out for you.

```
button.WaitForControlPropertyEqual(button.Enabled.ToString(), true);
```

Comment: Unfortunately your variant throws `System.NotSupportedException`. I changed it for `button.WaitForControlPropertyEqual(UITestControl.PropertyNames.Enabled, "true")` but it returns `false` if button was disabled initially and changed to enabled during time-out.